# How to set Spannable to TextView?

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, spannable

I have a `TextView` declared as follows..

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cc_journal_survey_next_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Next Survey: %s"/>
```

As you can see, **Next Survey** is bold and I want the string after it to not be bold. I am attempting to use a spannable as follows..

```
mNextTv = findViewById(R.id.cc_journal_survey_next_tv);

final SpannableString surveyName = new SpannableString(survey.getSurveyName());
        surveyName.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL),0, surveyName.length(), Spannable
                .SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mNextTv.setText(String.format(getContext().getString(R.string.cc_journal_survey_next), surveyName));
```

However my end result is

**Next Survey: Survey**

I thought that `Typeface.NORMAL` would take my spannable string and present it without bold.

What am I not understanding about this?

Comment: Firstly why do you use a typeFace if you want to keep the text normal !!

Comment: because w/o a typeFace.NORMAL, it turns bold because my textView is bold

Comment: Just use two separate TextViews. One bold, the other not. Put them together in something like a LinearLayout to make them look like they are one text piece, while you can controll each individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TextView has textStyle property set to bold. It overrides what you've set in your 'surveyName' variable. So my suggestion is to delete it and in your Spannable set span for the part of text that you want to be bold.

Try something like this:

```
final theWholeString = String.format(getContext().getString(R.string.cc_journal_survey_next), surveyName);
final SpannableString outputString = new SpannableString(theWholeString);
outputString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, END_OF_BOLD_AREA, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

mNextTv.setText(outputString);
```

And remove testStyle from your TextView.

Comment: Because I need "Next Survey" to be of bold type, should remove the bold and use Spannable for both Strings? Both strings being "Next Survey:" and my "survey name"?

Comment: I suggest rather to set just one span for the string you want to be bold and to remove the textStyle property from TextView.

Comment: I guess Im confused as to how im not doing that. As you can see above I .setSpan on my string of interest...."survey.getSurveyName()"

Comment: I got it now, I removed the bold property and set my SpannableString to

final SpannableString surveyName = new SpannableString(getContext()
                    .getString(R.string.cc_journal_survey_next) +
                    survey.getSurveyName());

This then allowed to just set the span of bold to the first part of string

Thanks for the help!